# Is it possible to use class as variable in PHP?

Tags: php, class, oop, magic-methods

I have a class as follows:

```
class Integer {

private $variable;

public function __construct($variable) {
   $this->varaible = $variable;
}

// Works with string only
public function __isString() {
 return $this->variable;
}

// Works only, If Im using the class as a function (i must use parenthesis)
public function __invoke() {
 return $this->variable;
}

}


$int = new Integer($variable);
```

I would like work with class as with variable like:

`$result = $int + 10;`

I don´t known, how can I return `$int;` ?

Comment: These are all the magic methods: https://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php. Doesn't look like it's possible.

Comment: `$result = $int + 10;` That `$int` and `10` have incompatible data types for addition

Comment: I would like to return somewhere in class (int) $this->variable;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP does not support overloading operators (which is the technical thing you're looking for). It doesn't know what to do with `+` when one of the operands is a `class Integer`, and there's no way to teach PHP what to do. The best you can do is implement appropriate methods:

```
class Integer {
    ..
    public function add(Integer $int) {
        return new Integer($this->variable + $int->variable);
    }
}

$a = new Integer(1);
$b = new Integer(2);
echo $a->add($b);
```

Comment: Thank you very much deceze. I was think it :-(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see Example 4 of php's [call_users_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) page;

```
<?php

class myclass {
    static function say_hello()
    {
        echo "Hello!\n";
    }
}

$classname = "myclass";

call_user_func(array($classname, 'say_hello'));
call_user_func($classname .'::say_hello'); // As of 5.2.3

$myobject = new myclass();

call_user_func(array($myobject, 'say_hello'));

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

`public function __construct($variable) {
   $this->varaible = $variable;
}`

are this typo or not? on $this->varaible ?